# nodejs keeps loading when Unhandled Promise Rejection Error

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm new to nodeJS I'm trying to select one single board based on request Params

```
router.get('/board/:id', gettingSingleBoard);
```

and this is the getting single board function

```
gettingSingleBoard = async function (req, res) {
  const id = req.params.id;
  const board = await Board.findOne({ _id: id });
  res.json(board);
};
```

when I search with valid ID it works well , but when I try to enter ID that is not exits console logs "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection" and it keeps loading and not returning with error or something

Comment: Just `try-catch` the code so that the exception handling is explicit.

Comment: `gettingSingleBoard.catch(errorHandler);` Why didn't you do this?

Comment: When using `await`, you HAVE to surround that with `try/catch` to catch rejected promises or the caller of `gettingSingleBoard()` has to catch rejected promises and handle the error there.  You have completely "avoided" appropriate error handling so you should not be surprised that it does not behave as desired when there's an error.

Answer (score 4):

You need to wrap your async code with try/catch. See the example:

```
gettingSingleBoard = async function (req, res) {
  const id = req.params.id;
  try {
      const board = await Board.findOne({ _id: id });
      res.json(board); 
  } catch(e) {
      res.status(404).send({type: "NotFoundException"})
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility would be catching the error to an error object:

```
res.json(
  await Board
          .findOne({ _id: id })
          .catch(e=>({error:500,message:e}))
);
```